# How can I keep track of the coin number available coins in a vending machine?

Tags: c++

I have a school project in c++  for a simple vending machine that accepts one-dollar-bills and give change in quarters, dimes, nickels. All the items cost less than 1 dollar .
But I need to add an extra ability to keep track of the available change in the machine, and I dont how to do it.
And this is the piece of code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //set the variables
    int Qav=5 ;
    int Dav=5 ;
    int Nav=5 ;
    int purchaseAmount ;
    cout << "Simple Vending Program for Adam Ashouri (Regular Version)" <<endl;
    cout <<endl;
    cout <<endl;
    cout << "Enter a purchase amount [5 - 100] -->";
    cin >> purchaseAmount;
    int chaneBack = 100 - purchaseAmount ;

    changecalculator ();

}
    void changecalculator ()
{
    int purchaseAmount ;
    int QBack ,DBack ,NBack ;
    int chaneBack = 100 - purchaseAmount ;

    if (purchaseAmount %5 == 0)
    {
        cout << "You entered a purchase amount of " << purchaseAmount << " cents." <<endl;
        cout <<endl;
        QBack = chaneBack / 25 ;
        DBack = (chaneBack % 25) / 10;
        NBack = (chaneBack %25 %10) / 5;
        cout <<"Your change of " <<chaneBack <<" cents is given as " <<QBack <<" Q, " <<DBack <<"          D,and " <<NBack <<" N." <<endl;
        int coinsNum = QBack + DBack + NBack;
        cout << "The value of your " <<coinsNum <<" coins adds up to " <<chaneBack <<" cents." <<endl;
        cout << "Thank you for using my program.";

    }
    else
    { 
        cout << "Unable to process an invalid purchase amout of " <<purchaseAmount <<" cents." <<endl;
        cout << "Thank you for using my program." <<endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your current program doesn't work, because you don't transfer `purchaseAmount` inside function `changecalculator()`. You need to do it this way:

1) Change signature of the function to this: `void changecalculator(int iPurchaseAmount)`

2) Send `purchaseAmount` inside the function (i.e. call it this way: `changecalculator(purchaseAmount);`)

3) Use value `iPurchaseAmount` inside the body of your function and remove line `int purchaseAmount;` from it.

And about your main question (saving of number of available coins):

Ok, you've added `Qav`, `Dav` and `Nav` (available coins) in the body of your program. It is right. Now you have to transfer these values inside your `changecalculator()` function. Try to use this signature of your function: `void changecalculator(int iPurchaseAmount, int& ioQav, int& ioDav, int& ioNav)` (these values will be available inside body of the function). And call this function this way: `changecalculator(purchaseAmount, Qav, Dav, Nav);`.

After it you need only to analyze these values and change it inside the function.  Let's add changeing of the values (it is necessary in case of many calls of this function). Just add following lines after calculation of `QBack`, `DBack` and `NBack`:

```
ioQav -= QBack;
ioDav -= DBack;
ioNav -= NBack;
```

And the most complex part of this task is analysis of values `ioQav`, `ioDav`, `ioNav` before calculation of `QBack`, `DBack` and `NBack`. Let's do it for quarters:

```
QBack = std::min(chaneBack / 25, ioQav);
```

It is calculation of the smallest value of two: available number of quarters and optimal number of quarters. So, this line calculates exactly what do you need. After it you can calculate number of dimes:

```
chaneBack -= QBack * 25; // subtract quarters
DBack = std::min(chaneBack / 10, ioDav);
```

If you understand this logic, you can complete it for `NBack`.

Comment: I need an algorithm in case one of the coins exhausted in the machine to use the other denominations. I thought about it a lot but i got a lot of if statements.

Comment: If you understand logic for quarters, dimes, nickels, you can support other coins.

Comment: what do you mean by ioDav ? is just a new variable?

Comment: @AdamRich, as I wrote in this answer, you need to transfer variables from function `main()` into function `changecalculator()`. To do it you need to extend set of parameters. Have you added `purchaseAmount` in parameters of `changecalculator()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. Actually I had to use `QBack = std::min(changeBack/25 , Qav);`. But I got it. My question wasnt clear because English is not my mother language. thanks again.

Comment: @AdamRich, great, you are absolutely right: there we have to use `min` (I've corrected my answer).